# "npm install -g yo" hangs in postinstall on windows

Tags: node.js, npm

attempting to install yo on windows with the command "npm install -g yo" goes through the whole process , but hangs when running

```
> yo@1.2.1 postinstall c:\npm\node_modules\yo
> node ./scripts/doctor
```

the node.exe process goes to 12-13% cpu (there are 8 cores, so it looks like the process is 100% cpu on the core it's attached to), and will stay at this point for 12 hours+

there are no error messages. 
I've tried clearing the cache, uninstalling and reinstalling etc, all to no avail.

```
npm@1.4.14
node@v0.10.29
```

I've tried the cmd prompt with and without admin privileges. I've also tried to use the --loglevel warn, and got no errors

Is there anyone else who's had this problem and can suggest a solution ?

Comment: As node uses a C++ compiler, check that you have one working without problems